# how to create a sha256 from an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, hash, sha

https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-hash

This package only supports SHA1.

Is there any other way that can work to create the SHA256 from an object?

Comment: Have you tried `hash(value, {algorithm: 'sha256'})`? Does `crypto.getHashes()` return `sha256` in your environment? Have you read the documentation? _"This package only supports SHA1."_ That's not what the documentation says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement *"This package only supports SHA1"* is wrong. The npm package `object-hash` supports multiple hash algorithms, depending on your environment.

The code

```
const hash = require('object-hash');

const obj = {};

console.log(hash(obj, { algorithm: 'sha256' }));
```

works with Node.js 16.20.0. You can get a list of supported algorithms with:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

console.log(crypto.getHashes());
```

I'm using CJS because you've used it in your other questions. Of course, you can do the same with ESM.